# NoClassDefFoundError when running JPOS Q2?

Tags: maven, jpos

Trying to setup JPOS Q2 for the first time through Maven / Intellij, and coming across an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleException
at Q2_Main.main(Q2_Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I downloaded JPOS through maven, and I've tried looking at dozens of threads on the error but cannot resolve it on my own

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q2_JPOS_TEST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

and I see it in my external libraries

[jpos in external library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUCD3.png)

```
import org.jpos.q2.Q2;

public class Q2_Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Q2 q2 = new Q2("src/main/java/deploy");
    q2.start();
}
```

}

Edit for steps that I did:

1. File -> New Project -> Maven Project (created the POM automatically)
2. Pasted the JPOS dependency from my main project into new POM file
3. Maven Clean + Install from within Intellij Maven Panel
4. Created Q2_Main.java
5. Hit green play button, which results in that error

Edit 2:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< org.example:Q2_JPOS_TEST >------------
```

---

```
[INFO] Building Q2_JPOS_TEST 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]-----------------------
```

---

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ 
Q2_JPOS_TEST ---
[INFO] org.example:Q2_JPOS_TEST:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.jpos:jpos:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache-extras.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.67:compile
[INFO]    +- org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:jar:1.67:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO]    +- org.javatuples:javatuples:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jline:jline:jar:3.19.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------    
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------    
[INFO] Total time:  2.205 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-17T15:43:38-07:00
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------- 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<servers>
    <server>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <id>artifactory</id>
    </server>
</servers>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <url>https://artifactory.company.com:443/central</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>artifactory</id>
  <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from the     
Maven Super POM
      to activate snapshots for both! -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

</profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
<!--make the profile active all the time -->
<activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Please, share the details of how you are trying to run it from IntelliJ, and try to embed the image instead of linking to it. I tried to edit the question myself, but the edit queue is full and I cannot.

Comment: Also, please put the complete content of your `pom.xml` so we can try to import it and reproduce your issue, the one you shared does not have the top element.

Comment: Pasted the rest of the pom file. Also I can't embed images, since stack overflow says I do not have enough reputation yet. My entire program is there in the post, just trying to play around with Q2 and see if I should switch my main project to it

Comment: Ok I understand, please, then show a step by step guide of what you did to create the project until how you did run it.

e.g. I created this file in this directory, then I created the project in intellij in this way, then .. and then so we can reproduce it and know what can be wrong

Comment: It seems the dependency that is not being added to the classpath is `org.osgi:core:6.0.0` Can you see if you see it in your external libraries? Can you show, in your question, because as a comment would be illegible, the output of the command `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: I do not see it in my external libraries. Edited question to include the mvn dependency:tree command

Comment: It seems your maven is not pulling the runtime dependencies

Comment: Can you show your `settings.xml`? please mask all sensitive data you could have there, the only it occurs to me for your maven not pulling those dependencies and mine yes, is something in your environment. Maven should be adding those runtime dependencies in the runtime classpath. To check where you need to look for your settings files: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: may be you can run `mvn --debug dependency:tree` to check if it provides some information about which is blocking the transitive runtime dependencies.

Comment: Added settings.xml to the post. Also tried your above debug command, but I don't see anything out of the ordinary. I could also share that if needed, though it is a very long output for an already long stack overflow post

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your `settings.xml` can you try to temporary move it out of the way and see what happens then when you get the dependency tree again? I would even temporary rename the entire `.m2` directory to start fresh.

Comment: Yep that did it. Started with a fresh .m2 folder, and borrowed settings.xml from a different team at my company. Still trying to pinpoint exactly what's needed to get it working before I can update the answer to this post, but in the meantime looks like I'm all set to start using Q2. Thanks!

Comment: My last answer tries to resume these interactions, if you think it is OK, could you mark it as the accepted answer? So others with the same problem know it is a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a step by step of what I did to tun your code:

1. Create an empty folder `/tmp/test-jpos`
2. Write the file `pom.xml` there with the content you shared.
3. In IntelliJ menu File -> Open and opened the `/tmp/test-jpos` folder
4. Create dir `src/main/java`
5. Create file `Q2_Main.java` in that directory with content you shared.
6. Run the project by hitting the play run button (the green triangle)

With those steps it ran OK.

However that is not the recommended way to run `Q2` I will expand on this later.

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step. Here's what I did:
1. File -> New Project -> Maven Project (created the POM automatically)
2. Pasted the JPOS dependency from my main project into new POM file
3. Maven Clean + Install
4. Created Q2_Main.java
5. Hit green play button, which results in that error 

Thanks for the help, If you don't mind, what is the recommended way to run Q2?

Comment: Please add this to the question itself, I would do it, but the edit queue is still full, also specify how you ran maven clean + install, outside the IDE or inside?

Comment: Performing the steps you mentioned, I can't reproduce your issue, so, it is something relative to your specific environment, or somehow the steps were slightly different, may be you need to be more precise, for instance, exactly what options did you select in the `New Project` wizzard, I don't see `maven project` option there, but selected Maven as build system, I assume you did that. Also if maven clean + install is performed in the console, and I don't update your maven project after that what I get is `java: package org.jpos.q2 does not exist` but if I update it I can run it.

Comment: Didn't you try with the steps from this answer? If not, why?

Comment: Edited the question to include the details. That's pretty much all I have done. You are right, there's no Maven Project, but I did select Maven as build system. Also, built maven from the Maven pane within Intellij itself.

Comment: As far as your latest comment, sorry I have not had the time during work to try out your steps. I will try ASAP, likely tomorrow

Comment: Also, Ran the above steps exactly as you had described, but still the same error

Comment: Yes, for some reason that I can't pinpoint  your maven is not pulling the `osgi` dependency, I don't know if it's because of a maven setting or due to maven version.

Answer (score 0):

I checked on the maven repository the library you are trying to use, jpos 2.1.6 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jpos/jpos/2.1.6), and I've seen it has a series of runtime dependencies. It seems you miss `org.osgi.core 6.0.0` judging from the stacktrace you posted. Make sure you have all the runtime dependencies needed in your classpath.

Comment: Is there no way to tell Maven to download those runtime dependencies automatically?

Comment: It does download it automatically! You can check it with "mvn dependency:tree" to make sure you have everything you need. Also, you should check you don't have different versions of the same dependency.  Anyway, I tried to run your project, and it works just fine. So my best bet here is that intellj is injecting the osgi lib into your project or something like that, and it conflicts with the maven dependency. Try to run it outside intellij and see if it works.

Comment: I edited the question with the output for mvn dependency:tree. I also tried to run it outside intellij, but still got the same error. I deleted target folder, then did mvn compile -> mvn clean install -> mvn package -> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=Q2_Main

Comment: Alright, it seems it does not download all the dependencies you need. The first thing I would try is mvn clean package -U. The -U option forces maven to check for missing releases/snapshots in your repository. If this does not work, I would go in the .m2/repository folder and delete jpos in there so it will be forced to download it fresh next time you build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last comment, the problem seems to be related to its maven installation.

To figure out if this could be an issue, one can perform the following steps.

1. First, try to move any possible maven setting in your local installation. Rename the user level `settings.xml` (in linux `~/.m2/settings.xml`) and if it's possible that you or someone modified the installation level `settings.xml` try to get the distribution default.
2. If after this the dependencies are correctly brought, then the problem is with that settings, you can try to apply the settings you need, item by item and check in every step, that the dependencies are resolved ok.
3. If step 1 didn't work, the problem may somehow be in the maven cache. Rename the entire `.m2` directory, and retry.
4. As in step 2, try to get back your setting from the old `settings.xml` and see if it breaks again.